# php code to count how many time a number appear in a row using INNER JOIN statement

Tags: php, mysql

Am trying to count how many time a number appear in a row(in order to calculate number of sale per person ) i have these table in my database `books`, `shelf`,  here is my code

```
$UBooks = $dbhandle->query("SELECT *  FROM books 
    INNER JOIN shelf ON books.id = shelf.bookid WHERE books.author_id = '$id';
    ");

    if ($UBooks->num_rows > 0)
    {
      while($row = $UBooks->fetch_assoc()) 
      {

        $ruid = $row["bid"];
          $title = $row["title"];
          $description = $row["description"];
          $bookurl = "../../".$row["bookurl"];
          $publish = $row["publish"];
          $price = $row["price"];
          $Fullname = $row["bookid"];



          if($publish == 1)
          {
            $publish = '<input type="checkbox" checked bid="'.$ruid.'" title="Click to Un-Publish Book" onchange="activateBook(this);" />';
          }
          else if ($publish == 0)
          {
            $publish = '<input type="checkbox" bid="'.$ruid.'" title="Click to Publish Book" onchange="activateBook(this);" />';
          }
          else if ($publish == 3)
          {
            $publish = '<input type="checkbox" bid="'.$ruid.'" title="Click to Publish Book" onchange="activateBook(this);" /> <label>For Review</label>';
          }
        $BooksTab .= '<tr>
                           <td>'.$title.'</td>  <td>'.$description.'</td> <td>'.$price.'</td>
                          <td>'.$Fullname.'</td>
                        </tr>';


      }
  }


?>
```

so am looking for a way to count the a number appear in the shelf table in `bookid` as row, for instance if 3 appears 7 time in the shelf table than it should calculate it and display it as number of sales=7

here is my shelf table structure [image: this is my shelf table]

why this one is my book table sturture
[image: why this is my book table]

Comment: Please post your table structure, but a simple `COUNT` and `GROUP BY` might solve your problem.

Comment: have posted my table structure

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Answer (score 0):

you probably don't need a JOIN just

```
 SELECT bookid, count(*)
 FROM shelf
 GROUP BY bookid
```

Comment: did not work?am using inner join because am getting value from 2 table

Comment: what didnt work? What result you got and what result you expect?